# Can't build. Build_Path error

Tags: sublimetext3, text-editor, buildpath

I synced my Sublime Text packages via a symbolic link to my Dropbox server. It didnt break my Sublime, but somehow something in conjunction with those actions resulted in an error message (full).

> Unable to find required project setting "build_path"

I'm trying to build with a custom build system, but the error appears seemingly with any build system. The custom build system is for the language gezel:

```
{
    "cmd" : ["/opt/gezel/bin/fdlsim ${file_base_name}.fdl 64"], // the build command
    "shell": true, // open the terminal
    "working_dir" : "$file_path",
}
```

I'm not (AFAIK) working with files as projects and merely as file-basis. So I don't know how to refer to the .sublime-project file. Maybe sublime expects it, but I want to just refer to the file as a standalone to be built with my build system.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: You'll need to add a lot more detail if you want to get any help. What were you doing when this message appeared? Is this the **full text** of the error, or was there more? What language were you using? What build system was selected? Did you have a project active, and if so what are the contents of the `.sublime-project` file? If you were using a custom build system, what are the contents of the `.sublime-build` file?

Comment: Fair enough. My sublime preference knowledge is limited and I didn't know exactly what to provide. I've edited the text to include the relevant information. Hope you can use it.